# Alternative to session_is_registered()

Tags: php, session

What is the alternative to the deprecated function `session_is_registered()` in PHP 5?

Here's my code:

```
ob_start();

session_start();

if(!session_is_registered(myusername))

{

    header("location:main_login.php");

}

ob_flush();
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

"You need to set and reference $_SESSION variables only." For example:

```
if( isset($_SESSION[$myusername]) )
```

From http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=263189.0

Answer (score 7):

on a side note, best use `$_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;`. Using the `$_SESSION[$myusername]` as a variable may overwrite existing variables in the session.

Answer (score 3):

But if you set anything in the session variable it will display you the protected page:
e.g.,

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION[$myusername])){
        echo "welcome to protected page.";
    }
    else {  
        header('location:login.php');
        die;     
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `session_id()`

```
if (!session_id()) {
 // do stuff
}
```

if there is no session id nothing will be returned. [(docs - session_id() )](http://ca.php.net/session_id)

Comment: you get a session_id() as soon as you call session_start(); the OP wants to see if a user is logged in.